# Running a code 1000 times and saving it in a R vector

Tags: r

I have a code that simulates number of turns taken until the first red ball is drawn from the bag (the bag originally has 1 red and 1 blue ball, and after each turn the ball is returned along with its same colour. So after n turns, there are n+2 balls in the bag).

```
k = 0
success = FALSE
while (success == FALSE) {
  k = k + 1
  if (rgeom(n, 1/(n+1)) == 1) success = TRUE
}
k
```

Now I want to run this code 1000 times by putting this loop inside another loop that runs 1000 times and save the results in an R vector called x. I have tried to put something like x[i] = n at the end of the ith loop and wrote for (i in 1:1000) at the start of the code above, but nothing is really working. Any advices?

Comment: Your object `n` is undefined.

Comment: `vec <- replicate(1000, { some code here })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following is a simulation of the problem described in the question.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible

result <- replicate(1000, {
  k <- 0
  success <- FALSE
  while(!success) {
    success <- rgeom(1, 1/(k + 2)) == 1
    k <- k + 1
  }
  k
})
barplot(table(result))
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
result <- replicate(1000, {
  k = 0
  success = FALSE
  while (success == FALSE) {
    k = k + 1
    if (rgeom(1, 1/(n+1)) == 1) success = TRUE
  }
  k
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have another one:

```r
result <- sapply(1:1000, 
                 function(x) {   
                   k = 0
                   success = FALSE
                   while (success == FALSE) {
                     k = k + 1
                     if (rgeom(n, 1/(n+1)) == 1) success = TRUE
                   }
                   return(k)
                 })
```

Comment: If you look at the source for `replicate` (from my answer), you'll see that it is effectively doing this same thing: `sapply` over a vector that is ignored, solely for the expression. I don't think there is any real performance difference between the two, though this is slightly closer to barebones.

Comment: I prefer your solution, because it's (imho) easier to understand. I wasn't aware that both ways are basically the same. Thanks for the insight! :-)

Comment: I agree, it seems more *declarative*, whereas glancing at `sapply` one might wonder why the argument is being ignored.